# Need help configuring Apache, MySQL, PHP on Centos Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I am new to Linux (CentOS) and have been trying to setup 
up this web application https://github.com/craigrodway/printmaster on CentOS for the 
last couple hours.

The instruction from the author is a bit vague for a newbie like me:

- Create directory on webserver to store files (configure as virtual
  host or subdir)
- Copy all Print Master files to the folder you just created
- Create a new directory called session where you extracted the files and make it writeable
- Create a new username and database in MySQL
- Import the printmaster.sql file into the new database
- Edit the
  $db line in inc/init.php to reflect your database details Invent your
  own security (.htaccess, integrated Windows authentication...)

I try to follow the instruction from guide in the wiki section but still could not get it to work: https://github.com/craigrodway/printmaster/wiki/Installation-on-Linux

**Here is a history of what I did**

1. Installed / configured Apache Server following this instruction:
   http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/apache-server *(Visited localhost
   in the web browser and saw an Apache Test Page)*
2. Installed / configured PHP following this intruction:
   http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/php *(Visited localhost/phpinfo in
   the web browser, and there's the phpinfo output. So it works!)*
3. Installed / configured MySQL

**--- FILES ---**

```
[root@localhost ~]# cd /tmp
[root@localhost ~]# wget [url]
https://github.com/craigrodway/printmaster/tarball/master[/url] --no-check-certificate
[root@localhost ~]# tar zxvf master
[root@localhost ~]# mv craigrodway-printmaster-af9843d/* /root/Desktop/printmaster/
```

Created 'session' directory is in the printmaster directory, made it writable

```
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir session
[root@localhost ~]# chmod 755 session
```

**--- DATABASE ---**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(enter the password for root user)

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'printers'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'printersPASS';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE printers;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON printers.* TO 'printers'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit;
```

**--- IMPORT SQL FILE ---**

Import the printmaster.sql as instructed

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p printers < printmaster.sql
```

Open init.php and edit the $db line

```
[root@localhost ~]# vi inc/init.php
```

Change $db to:

```
$db = new fDatabase('mysql', 'printers', 'printers', 'printersPASS', 'localhost');
```

**--- Now I set up VirtualHost on httpd ---**
First of all, do I even need to set up virtual host?

Created the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/testprintmaster.conf with the following text:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /root/Desktop/printmaster
  ServerName testprintmaster
  ServerAlias [url]www.testprintmaster.com[/url]
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
```

**--- RESULT ---**

That's it! But when I visit www.testprintmaster.com on firefox, Apache directs it to a search page ... WTF!?

I check the syntax check on VirtualHost configuration

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/sbin/httpd -S

VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443   localhost.localdoman (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
*:80        is a NameVirtualHost
    default server testprintmaster (/etc/httpd/conf.d/testprintmaster.conf:2)
    port 80 namevhost testprintmaster (/etc/httpd/conf.d/testprintmaster.conf:2)
Syntax OK
```

What did I do wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you visiting www.printmaster.com? It sounds like you're configuring your server locally, so you should make sure testprintmaster resolves to your localhost (i.e. `ping testprintmaster` succeeds). If it doesn't you should add `127.0.0.1    testprintmaster` record to /etc/hosts and then try accessing it via http://testprintmaster.

Comment: +1 (in 50 minutes when I have votes again).  This is correct.  Op needs to add the domain to the hosts file to be able to access it.  Or not use a vhost at all and just access `http://localhost`

Comment: BluesRock, 'www.printmaster.com' was a typo. I actually tried 'testprintmaster' and it re-directed me a search page. I also try to add 127.0.0.1 testprintmaster to /etc/hosts. It returns this message " Forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at testprintmaster Port 80"

Comment: I followed drew00 suggestion and not use VirtualHost and it works. But Eventually I need to set up VirtualHost because apache will be serving multiple services.